# Splash Screen/Launch Screen issue for iPad (version 10.3 or above)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

The splash screen I added for iPad Air 2 with version 10.3.1 is not loading in the webapp I created (in HTML/JavaScript).

I don't know what is causing it because the webapp icon is working absolutely fine. Is it regarding the dimensions (width or height) or is it with the latest iOS update?

I know there is a link tag like the following:

```
link rel="apple-touch-startup-image"
```

What is the proper link tag?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I was not aware of it.